# How to filter all the values of a string from Array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have an array that contains the tags values, now how to  return all the respective tag objects that contain a search tag ??

I have an array like this:

```
[
    {"tags": ["a"]},
    {"tags": ["a","b"]},
    {"tags": ["a","c"]},
    {"tags": ["a","b","c"]},
    {"tags": ["a","d"]}
]
```

For "a" it should return all the objects

For "b" it should return 2 objects (index 1 and index 4)

For "c" it should return 2 objects (index 2 and index 3)

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you've worked on to solve the problem should include a [mcve], and be included in your question.

Comment: Iterate them and look through the tags? Please show us what you tried. If you need a hint: `filter` and `includes`.

Comment: Familiarize yourself with [how to access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON](/q/11922383/4642212) and how to [create objects](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) and use the available static and instance methods of [`Object`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#Static_methods) and [`Array`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Static_methods).

Comment: [Edit] your post and clarify the search requirements. Should the input `"a"` return all objects because the string `"a"` is exactly included in all arrays, or because `"a"` is a substring of any string in all arrays?

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you can use this one (using [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)):

```js
const search = str => {
  const tags = [
    { tags: ['a'] },
    { tags: ['a', 'b'] },
    { tags: ['a', 'c'] },
    { tags: ['a', 'b', 'c'] },
    { tags: ['a', 'd'] }
  ]

  return tags.filter(x => x.tags.includes(str))
}

console.log(search('b'))
```

Note that this searches with strict casing.